# iTunes Store Sign in Failure: "%%appleId%%"

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, face-id

In the past two days I've tried to make an in app purchase in two apps*. I've successfully made purchases in the past, but not with these apps, and both times yesterday and today I've gotten an odd failure. I'm using an iPhone XS Max.

Here's what I do:

1. Click on remove adds in either app, which gives the "Double click to pay" dialogue.
2. Double click the side button
3. Face ID checks and gives a checkmark with "Done" below
4. Then I get this [image: Verification Required]
5. Continue takes me to Settings, checks Face ID and shows my billing information with the CVV not filled in.
6. Input CVV and click Done, I get another Face ID check and get this[image: Sign In to iTunes Store]

Both Cancel and Buy seem to do the same thing at this point, just drop me back to the Account Settings page.

That "%%appleId%%" seems super sketchy. I'm keeping an eye on my credit card and haven't seen any weird charges. If I manually follow the path from the first dialogue I get to the same "Account Settings" page and get the same dialogue with "%%appleId%%"

Otherwise, this seems like it could be a bug. Can I do anything to get around this ***%%appleId%%*** error dialog where it won’t let me enter my password or make a purchase?

*(removing ads for both [Sudoku Master Edition](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sudoku-master-edition-logic/id1260190370) and [Wordscapes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wordscapes/id1207472156))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went to System Preferences > Face ID and Passcode (which required me to enter my *device* password) and turned off *Face ID* for the App Store.

Once I did that, I attempted to make an in app purchase and was again sent to verify my info, but this time was able to do this successfully after inputting my CVV.

I then turned FaceID back on for the AppStore.

Comment: this was inspired by @sembiance's answer but after reading it closely every step was actually different, so I went ahead and posted this answer.

Answer (score 5):

I had this happen to me and what worked was intentionally failing the Touch ID (or face I think it doesnt matter) so it gives you the option to type in your apple id password

Comment: Genius!  I had to do this on a couple of different Touch ID dialogs but it eventually broke me out of the stupid cycle. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me as well a few days ago. I fixed it by turning off the passcode to unlock the iPad (which required me to enter the apple id password) and turning off Face Time for App Store purchases. Then I turned passcode back on (which again required my apple id password). Then when I went to do an in-app purchase it failed, required verification, but this time it actually asked for a password rather than giving the "%%appleId%%" error. The in-app purchased completed. I then turned face time back on for App Store purchases and now face time works just great for in-app purchases, no errors or failed verifications anymore.

As a developer, this has got to be happening to more folks than just us. You'd think Apple would have maetris that would be showing a general drop in in app purchases, but not a corresponding drop to app purchases and they would track the problem down and fix it.

There are also anecdotal reports that you might have to fail your fingerprint / Face ID or disable / re-enable more than once to clear this error condition. On most, the first fix works, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can intentionally fail the FaceID or turn off FaceID for AppStore. **Both answers are correct.**

But you can also turn off FaceID and after the purchase set it up again. This will regenerate your tokens definitely preventing this to happen again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue trying to make an in-app purchase on [Foreign Numbers](https://foreignnumbers.com) and neither of the above solutions worked for me unfortunately.

For me, I was able to make an in-app purchase with no troubles after rebooting my iPhone XS Plus. The in-app purchase seemed to take a little longer to initialise, so maybe that was a good sign...?

In any case, this doesn't seem to be the fault of any developer, I believe it's on Apple's end.

Answer (score 1):

I turned off all Touch ID here (System Preferences > Touch ID & Passcode) and then it worked.  And then I turned the all back on.